# How to create org-mode recipe for melpa?

Tags: org-mode, package-repositories, package-development

I'm trying to use `github.com/milkypostman/melpa` for creating a package from my own org-mode git repository. There are many recipes which I can create by `make recipes/foo` command, but there isn't the recipe for org-mode.

I look org-mode.rcp, el-get's recipe - it uses special commands for building. Also I know that elpa org-mode package and el-get org-mode package have slightly different file structure: el-get org-mode package has `etc` and `lisp` directories, but elpa org-mode package has few additional files.

Comment: Out of curiosity, any particular reason why you need to build org-mode through Melpa's machinery?

Comment: I want to have my own mini repository with patched packages. I use el-get now, but it is difficult to use elpa and el-get together because of resolving dependencies. Emacs 24.4 has variable `package-pinned-archives` for specific archives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/quelpa/quelpa uses recipes in MELPA's format to build your desired packages from source and installs them using the built-in Emacs package manager